# Dividing third derivative by second derivative

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I've been studying the shape of the cable in suspension bridges (for my school essay). I have derived a differential equation which models the shape

$y'' = m\sqrt{1 + (y')^{2}} + n$

where $m$ is the weight density of the cable over the horizontal component of the tension and $n$ is the weight density of the bridge deck over the horizontal component of the tension. I attempt to solve by moving $n$ to the LHS and squaring both sides

$(y'')^{2} - 2ny'' + n^{2} = m^{2} + m^{2}(y')^{2}$

and then taking the derivative of both sides

$2y''y''' - 2ny''' = 2m^{2}y'y''$

At this point I have no idea how to transform the equation in order to solve it besides dividing both sides by $y''$. The problem here is with the $2ny'''$ term (on the lhs). May I divide the third derivative by the second derivative in the following way?

$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{d}{dx}\frac{dy}{dx} \cdot \frac{dx}{d}\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{d}{dx}$

Is this valid?

Comment: What makes you think it is?

Comment: What should make me think it is not?

Comment: No, you may not do that. It's nonsense.

Comment: That's why Leibniz notation is bad for beginners.

Comment: From the first line, do $z = dy/dx$

Comment: @Kaynex what would it change?

Comment: I can't understand what could be the result of the division. Can you help me understand what sort of cancellation you think is possible here: $ y'' = 2y' $?

Comment: You would turn your second order DE into a first order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Liebniz notation, the "d" is not a variable, but a function, and $d^2y$ does NOT refer to $d\cdot d\cdot y$ but rather to $d(d(y))$.  Likewise, while the second derivative *might* be $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$, it is more formally $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{d^2x}{dx^2}$, with  $d^2x$ reducing to 0 if $x$ is the independent variable.

Thus, if $x$ is the independent variable, and you divide the third derivative by the second derivative, you would get:

$$\frac{d^3y}{dx^3} \cdot \frac{dx^2}{d^2y} = \frac{d^3y}{dx\,d^2y}$$

This is because the real way you should think about it is:

$$\frac{d(d(d(y)))}{(d(x))^3} \cdot \frac{(d(x))^2}{d(d(y))} = \frac{d(d(d(y)))}{d(x)\,d(d(y))}$$

If $x$ is not the independent variable, you would get a huge mess (the full expansion of higher derivatives get messier with each order).

You can't reduce the nested $d()$ function any more than you could reduce a nested $\sin()$ function.

Comment: By the way, in response to @Math_QED, I find Liebniz is extremely great at getting students to think deeply about differentials, but *only* if they are taught them correctly.  Most Calc books just skip over thinking about differentials at all, and just go with "do it this way because I said".  That, in fact, does lead people to use them badly.  Instead, if you are taught that $dx$ is just a shorthand for $d(x)$, then all of a sudden students start using them better, and actually *understanding* the notation being used.

Comment: I think you could have something to say to this: https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/13693/9535

Comment: Harto - thanks for the heads up!